# Unknown provider : error when trying to use module.config and jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an Asp.Net MVC App where i set the following in my cshtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (app) {
        app.constant('appPath', '@appPath');
    })(angular.module('myApp'));
</script>
```

I have this in my controller code.

```
app.config([
    "$routeProvider", "appPath", ($routeProvider: angular.route.IRouteProvider, appPath: string) => {
      //
    }
]);
```

Then i have the following jasmine spec .

```
 describe("mytest", () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
                module("myApp",($provide: ng.auto.IProvideService) => {
                    $provide.value("appPath", "http://testpath");
                });
            });
         it('does its thing', function () {
            // some test
        });});
```

But it throws the following error,failed to instantiate module myApp due to error:[$injector:unpr] unknown provider 'appPath'.
Is this because app.constant, that is inside the cshtml file does not get set, when i am running in test mode ?

How can i add appPath to the config during Testing ?

Comment: Before your `(angular.module('myApp'))` you appear to have an extra `)`

Comment: I don't see any extra ) ?

Comment: It isn"t extra but it shouldn't be there because it's closing the function early

Comment: Its an IIFE and its correctly setting the constant to the module.